# How to pass in different classes to a element directive

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an element `directive`, which is to be reused. 
But the `background-color` needs to be changed according to the usage.
Hence a class needs to be injected dynamically into the `directive`, each time the `directive` is called.

`directive` name is `tabset`

**tabset** template:

```
<ul>
  ........ HTML STUFF .......
</ul>
```

It is to this `<ul>` tag that I need to add classes.

I would prefer an answer on lines of creating an `attribute` directive which can be passed onto the `tabset` directive.
Something like shown below:

**1st example**

```
<tabset colorblack>
</tabset>
```

**2nd example**

```
<tabset colororange>
</tabset>
```

where `colorblack` and `colororange` would be the attribute `directives`.

If something like this is not posiible, then do suggest the proper answers
*And please note:

Eventhough i have mentioned about changing colors, when it comes to real time, it is not just changing colors, so i definitely need to pass in `class`.*

DO let me know in case the question is not clear.Thanks in advance

Comment: just make the attribute color='orange' or color='black'

Comment: it is not color alone..... so i need to pass in a class..

Comment: then use it as a class, just use the same attribute and handle it in the directive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually quite simple, and you really really don't need a directive for that.

You do:

```
<tabset tab-class="colorblack">
</tabset>
```

And in your directive (assuming isolated scope):

```
scope: {
    tabClass: "@"
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<ul class="{{tabClass}}">
   ....
</ul>
```

Comment: even i thought this should work............  but not working . `{{tabclass}}` not resolving in HTML... hmmm let me see